# Chrome extension: Different session on every tab in single window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How to make a new/unique session when `chrome.tabs.create` called, even if it's in same domain that was already opened before??

There is no direct option that allow `chrome.tabs.create` to "Start" new session even in same domain.

Comment: There's no such thing in Chrome so you'll have to imitate this by adding/removing cookie headers via chrome.webRequest API, but it'll be still quite limited. In Firefox you can use browser.contextualIdentities